# Threading Question - What happens if no threads available in the thread pool?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following code:

```
CancellationTokenSource cancelSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
_cancelTokenList.Add(cancelSource);

CancellationToken token = cancelSource.Token;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
   StartTest(token);
}, token);
```

Will an exception get thrown if no threads are available to service the request for a new task, or will it just wait until a thread becomes available? If it waits, how long will it wait?

Comment: Randy, what is the 'token' for in this sample?

Comment: @Henk - So I can cancel the task at some point later if desired.

Comment: Yeah right. But what's the point in relation to "available threads" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MSDN:

> You can queue as many thread pool requests as system memory allows. If there are more requests than thread pool threads, the additional requests remain queued until thread pool threads become available.
>
> The threads in the managed thread pool are background threads. That is, their IsBackground properties are true. This means that a ThreadPool thread will not keep an application running after all foreground threads have exited.

It will waits until one is available, or your application exits.

Answer (score 2):

It will just wait until a thread is available. As far as I'm aware, it will wait as long as it takes to get a thread. If you cancel it while it's still waiting for a thread, it just becomes cancelled immediately, and the user code will never run.

Comment: You must be Lucky Luke.. faster on the trigger than your own shadow.

Comment: If you cancel a task before it gets a chance to start the task status will go from WaitingToRun directly to Cancelled and the task is never started.

Comment: @Henk: I believe that's only the case if the task has already started. I *think* it can notice and self-cancel if it hasn't got as far as calling the user code. I haven't tested this though.

Comment: @Colin, @Jon, Yes because token is also fed to Startnew() here.

Answer (score 2):

A Task is handed to a Scheduler. The (default) TPL scheduler manages a handful of Worker Threads and assigns the Tasks to those Threads. If no Thread is available your Task will wait in a Queue. If too many Tasks are queuing up the scheduler/threadpool will slowly create new Threads (at a rate of 2 / second).

You show but don't mention a CancellationToken. It can only be used to request a cancellation <strike>so I suspect your StartTest() will be executed even if the token was cancelled while the Task was queued</strike>.